# I need to generate log file based on time stamp by end Script RUN and need to send that log file via SMTP

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I have below script which was running every 15 mins once. But i need to create log file by end of each execution and that log file need to send via SMTP enabled further. Please help me with this script modifications.

---

### Existing script

`robocopy \\Smas-test-1\D$\pap\Uploads\ \\Smas-test-2\D$\pap\Uploads\ *.* /E /MT:30`

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy has built in logging with the `/LOG` argument.

```
robocopy C:\source\ D:\destination\ *.* /LOG:D:\robocopy.log
```

You can attach that log as an attachment using the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7

```bsh
Send-MailMessage -Attachments "D:\robocopy.log" -To "someone@mail.com" -From "me@mail.com" -Subject "Robocopy log" -Body "See attached log" -SMTPServer "smtp.domain.com"
```

Comment: Thank you @retry W.  Let me check if this fits my requirement.